# SwiftUI: High memory usage when using Image as label in NavigationLink

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I want to display a menu using Image as a label on NavigationLink, but when I run the apps on real device as well as simulator. The memory usage on debug session shows around 400MB, but when I remove the image and change them to text, the memory usage shows only around 20MB and if I change all label with the same image, the memory usage shows around 80MB. what happen?? I want to use image as label on my NavigationLink without using a lot memory usage, any idea how?

here's the code

```
struct HomeMenu: View{
    var body: some View{
        GeometryReader{ geometry in
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false){
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: ChooseServiceLocationView()){
                        MainMenu(image: "service_location_new_final")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.44, height: geometry.size.height * 0.66)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: BookingServiceView()){
                        MainMenu(image: "booking_service_new_final")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.44, height: geometry.size.height * 0.66)
                    }
                }
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: DealerLocationView()){
                        MainMenu(image: "dealer_location_new_final")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.44, height: geometry.size.height * 0.66)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: BookTestDriveView()){
                        MainMenu(image: "booking_test_drive_new_final")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.44, height: geometry.size.height * 0.66)  
                    }
                }
                HStack{
                    NavigationLink(destination: VehicleLineUpView()){
                        MainMenu(image: "vehicle_line_up_new_final")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.44, height: geometry.size.height * 0.66)
                    }
                    NavigationLink(destination: SellMyCarView()){
                        MainMenu(image: "sell_my_car_new_final")
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 0.44, height: geometry.size.height * 0.66)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct MainMenu: View{
    var image: String
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            Image(image)
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of images are you displaying? Might it be possible that you are displaying very large image files and hence the images themselves consume a very large amount of memory?

Comment: my image format is JPEG, with 1200x1600 dimensions, and the size is 246KB. is that too big for image button?

Comment: Oh I see now, thanks for reminding me about my image files. Just resizing the image smaller to 300x400 and 12KB size. now my memory usage only 25MB. thanks again!

Comment: Remember that image file size != image size in memory. JPEG is a very efficient format for compressing images, but to render the image on screen, iOS needs to fully decompress it. The 1600x1200 resolution of your image means the size in *memory* for your image is around 1600x1200x4 = 7.68 MB (that’s pixel width times height times 4 bytes to represent the RGBA value of each pixel).

Comment: Hi @PhilipDukhov, this isn’t my question. It looks like resizing the image (original was 1200x1600 JPEG) solved the problem.